# Need help regarding customer pole display ,i am unable to send commands to it through serial port COM1

Tags: java, serial-port

I got assigned a task to communicate with line display or customer display its model VFD220E its baud rate 9600 N 8 1, and 20 characters 2 lines display. I had manual but while I am trying to send commands. Its no picking it up it just prints like string. Any help will be greatful thanks in advance. Below is my code.

```
  CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM1");
  if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned())
  {
      System.out.println("Port in use!");
  }
  else {
  System.out.println(portIdentifier.getName());

  SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) portIdentifier.open("ListPortClass", 300);
  int b = serialPort.getBaudRate();
  System.out.println(Integer.toString(b));
  serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);


  OutputStream mOutputToPort = serialPort.getOutputStream();
  InputStream mInputFromPort = serialPort.getInputStream();
  String ESC=" 1B  51  41  ";//hex codes
  String CR="0D";//hex codes
  String mValue = ESC+" Testing Phase"+CR;//to display on top line.
  String clear ="0C";
  System.out.println("beginning to Write . \r\n");
  mOutputToPort.write(clear.getBytes());
  mOutputToPort.write( mValue.getBytes());
  mOutputToPort.flush();
  System.out.println("Command Written to Port. \r\n");
  mOutputToPort.flush();
  System.out.println("Waiting for Reply \r\n");
  //Thread.sleep(500);
  byte mBytesIn [] = new byte[20];
  mInputFromPort.read(mBytesIn);
  mInputFromPort.read(mBytesIn);
  String value = new String(mBytesIn);
  System.out.println("Response from Serial Device: "+value);
  mOutputToPort.close();
  mInputFromPort.close();
  serialPort.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to send the control commands as text.
You can't just write`" 1B  51  41  "` as a String and send them to the display. The getBytes() method of String gives you a byte representation of the UTF-8 String and not the bytes 0x1B, 0x51 and 0x41.

You have to send the real byte values 0x1B, 0x51 and 0x41 to the display. Either by sending bytes or by using escape sequences in your String, i.e. in decimal notation `\027\081\065`.

See this [link](http://www.seetron.com/vfd220.html) for some common commands in hex and decimal notation.

Comment: thanks for your answer it works but i still have problem for ESC -\027 and i send text(testing phase) after that code .it displays "-1 testing phase" i dont have any idea y its printing -1 before testing phase. please help me if u have any idea about it ..thanks once again

Comment: I looked a bit at your ESC sequence and I think what you want to do is to clear the column and position the cursor in the top left corner (home). You don't need an escape sequence for this. Just send the bytes \017 and \001. But unfortunately I don't have a VFD220E to play with so I can't verify this.